# Can I add PushStreamContent to MultipartFormDataContent without HttpClient buffering whole request?

Tags: c#, .net, post, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a large file in an HTTP POST, along with some other data, using a `MultipartFormDataContent`. To send the file in chunks, I am using a `PushStreamContent` which writes chunks of data from my file stream to output stream, flushing after each write:

```
PushStreamContent pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) => {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    do {
        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        stream.Flush();
    }
    while(bytesRead != 0);
    stream.Close();
});
```

If I POST this `HttpContent` using the following code, everything works fine:

```
new HttpClient().PostAsync(destinationUrl, pushStreamContent);
```

If, however, this `PushStreamContent` is added to a `MultipartFormDataContent`, as follows:

```
MultipartFormDataContent postForm = new MultipartFormDataContent {
    {stringContent, "atom"},
    {pushStreamContent, "binary"}
};
```

and *that* is posted, then I receive an `OutOfMemoryException` within the lambda of the `PushStreamContent`. Presumably, the `HttpClient` is buffering the *whole* of the `MultipartFormDataContent` into memory, which fails as the request content is very large. I would like the client to defer to the flushing of the contained `PushStreamContent`. Is this possible? I am using .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request is being buffered because `HttpClient` needs to know the total length of the request in order to set the Content-Length header. A `PushStreamContent` object [always returns false](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/PushStreamContent.cs) for `TryComputeLength(out long)`.

Thus the solution is to create a sub-class of `PushStreamContent` which *does* know its length:

```
class PushStreamContentWithLength : PushStreamContent {
    public PushStreamContentWithLength(Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext> onStreamAvailable, long streamLength) : base(onStreamAvailable) {
        mStreamLength = streamLength;
    }

    readonly long mStreamLength;

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length) {
        length = mStreamLength;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If one of these is added to a `MultipartFormDataContent`, the data is pushed to the stream during an HTTP post, rather than being pre-loaded into memory.